# How to solve this error "http://struts.apache.org/tags-html cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application"

Tags: html, xml, struts2, struts

I am developing struts2 application in JSP i am getting this error

"http://struts.apache.org/tags-html cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application"

Should I have to include struts-taglib.jar , but this jar file not there in lib folder of struts2 . please help me to resolve this.

Comment: what all jars you have in your classpath and can you show what tab lib you have included in your jsp files

Comment: Struts1 is dead, and so its taglibs. Stop using it, if you are using Struts2, use Struts2 taglibs: `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>`